# spservices.js.Error:- Uncaught (in > promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading > 'LookupList')

Tags: javascript, development, spfx-webparts, spservices

Inside our SPFx web part we have the following code inside the `spservices.js` code:-

```
spservices.prototype.getLookupFieldOptions = function (siteUrl, listId, fieldInternalName) {
        return __awaiter(this, void 0, void 0, function () {
            var fieldOptions, web, results, options, _i, options_1, option, error_14;
            return __generator(this, function (_a) {
                switch (_a.label) {
                    case 0:
                        fieldOptions = [];
                        _a.label = 1;
                    case 1:
                        _a.trys.push([1, 5, , 6]);
                        web = new Web(siteUrl);
                        return [4 /*yield*/, web.lists.getById(listId)
                                .fields.usingCaching()
                                .filter("InternalName eq '" + fieldInternalName + "'")
                                .select("LookupList", "LookupWebId", "LookupField")
                                .top(1)
                                .get()];
                    case 2:
                        results = _a.sent();
                        if (!results) return [3 /*break*/, 4];
                        return [4 /*yield*/, web.lists.getById(results[0].LookupList)
                                .items.usingCaching()
                                .select("ID", results[0].LookupField)
                                .getAll()];
                    case 3:
                        options = _a.sent();
                        if (options && options.length > 0) {
                            for (_i = 0, options_1 = options; _i < options_1.length; _i++) {
                                option = options_1[_i];
                                fieldOptions.push({
                                    key: option.ID,
                                    text: option[results[0].LookupField]
                                });
                            }
                        }
                        _a.label = 4;
                    case 4: return [3 /*break*/, 6];
                    case 5:
                        error_14 = _a.sent();
                        return [2 /*return*/, Promise.reject(error_14)];
                    case 6: return [2 /*return*/, fieldOptions];
                }
            });
        });
    };
```

but on runtime the SPFx web part will return this error and it will keep loading forever:-

> calendar-web-part_a87ac4ce95dc9057c9f00ccd9727c133.js:1 Uncaught (in
> promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'LookupList')

this is the piece of code which is returning the error:-

```
return [4 /*yield*/, web.lists.getById(results[0].LookupList)
```

as follow:-

[image]

any advice on this please?

Comment: Why are you using SPServices in your SPFx web part?  Can you post your webpart code where you are actually using SPServices?

Comment: @DylanCristy thanks for your reply. yes i am using SPServices.. and the sample code shows how i am using it and which code is  returning the error... is this what you are asking for ? thanks

Comment: What you posted looks like it might be the SPServices source code to me.(?)  Unless you are extending SPServices with your own custom function? Are we talking about the same [SPServices](https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/index.html)?

Comment: @DylanCristy yes i am using https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/index.html and the error i am getting is inside the spservice.js

Comment: Right, so what I am asking is for you to show the code where _your_ code calls the SPServices function that then leads to the error.  Show how your code uses SPServices.

Comment: @DylanCristy i can not post the whole code inside the question, as it will exceed the characters limit.. so i upload the type script file inside this url @ https://1drv.ms/t/s!At147xVvrdC_g1bXKUk9rhwfVCtK?e=lny4kw  .. hope this helps thanks

Comment: I don't think we're talking about the same SPServices, or if we are, I have never seen SPServices used the way you are using it. SPServices, at least the one that I know, is a jQuery library, which means jQuery has to be loaded to use it.  You don't load jQuery in the code you linked to. Also, I have never known SPServices to have a constructor function that takes a SPFx web part context as an argument.  Also, some of the functions you are calling, like `getLookupFieldOptions` and `getChoiceFieldOptions` I do not see anywhere in the documentation for SPServices.  So, sorry, but I can't help.

Comment: @DylanCristy yes you are correct, sorry this web part has been developed using another developer, and i am doing some modification to it.. so the `spservices.js` that is been used is just a custom JavaScript and does not have to to with the https://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/index.html...

Comment: Can you show us the code you have in `spservices` file you imported using `import spservices from '../../services/spservices';`?

Comment: @GaneshSanap yes sure as the code will exceed the limits on this question, so i uploaded the code inside my one-drive; spservices.ts code @ https://1drv.ms/t/s!At147xVvrdC_g1bXKUk9rhwfVCtK and the spservices.js @ https://1drv.ms/u/s!At147xVvrdC_g1c8_GnzTMBjbG9O .. please have a look and let me know.. thanks

Comment: Are you passing correct `fieldInternalName` to `getLookupFieldOptions()` function? Add breakpoint at line no. 548 in `spservices.ts` file & check if you are getting correct `results`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem on that **"Select"** function, it is trying to read some sort of nested properties in each value.

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'LookupList') : this error is thrown when the caller is expecting a **"Promise"** to be returned and instead it is receiving **"undefined"**

So I assume to replace what you want to return on variables like the following :

```
var SPListWithFilteredItems = web.lists.getById(listId).fields.usingCaching().filter("InternalName eq '"+ fieldInternalName + "'").select("LookUpList","LookupWebId","LookupField").top(1).get();

return SPListWithFilteredItems;
```

Try one by one, at first try :

```
 web.lists.getById(listId)
```

Then

```
web.lists.getById(listId).fields.usingCaching()
```

Then

```
web.lists.getById(listId).fields.usingCaching().filter("InternalName eq '"+ fieldInternalName + "'")
```

... etc and let me know of the results.

Cordially.